# Why does the code below log undefined for a.bar?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I wrote the code below to set a *trap* for the internal prototype get routine for `proxy_a` but the code doesn't seem to work as expected.

```js
var base = {
  foo: 100
}

var a = {
  bar: 10
};

var proxy_a = new Proxy(a, {
  getPrototypeOf: function(target) {
    return base;
  }
});

// make proxy_a the prototype of b
var b = Object.create(proxy_a);

console.log(b.bar);
console.log(b.foo);
```

Here's the output

```
>> 10
>> undefined
```

The problem is with the second log statement. I expect the access to `b.foo` to resolve to the `foo` property of the `base` object but that doesn't happen.

Can anyone please explain what am I doing wrong, preferentially with a reference to the ECMAScript spec?

Comment: The code that you have written is analogous to the `get` method in Proxy, but not for `getPrototypeOf`. The trap needs to be triggered and MDN says there are five ways to do it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/getPrototypeOf#five_ways_to_trigger_the_getprototypeof_trap

Comment: (And this is easily demonstrated by putting a `console.log` in the `getPrototypeOf` function--it isn't executed in the snippet's flow.)

Comment: Yeah, I have recently seen that and read some of ECMAScript's documentation. Now the thing is how do I *actually implement* this kind of idea in JavaScript?

Comment: I believe you'd have to implement a GET trap that implements this behavior (i.e. delegating to some other object).

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, I was already trying that and it worked. I just wonder, is it performance-wise OK? Can you shed some light on the performance aspect of using `Proxy`?

Comment: It will probably be worse than if the JS engine makes these calls internally but the question is whether it really matters in your particular application. You can only know that by measuring.

Comment: Like, would it possible to kind of approximate *how much worse could this be*?

Comment: @coderboy [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It looks like](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-get-p-receiver) accessing a property on the proxy object without a get handler will simply delegate the property access to the proxy target. It's basically the same as doing `a.foo`. That means `foo` is looked for on *`a`'s prototype*, not the proxy object's prototype (which would trigger `getPrototypeOf`).

> 6. Let *trap* be ? GetMethod(*handler*, "get").
> 7. If *trap* is **undefined**, then
>    7.a Return ? *target*.[[Get]](*P*, *Receiver*).